# Creating a table such that there are arrows between columns

Tags: tables, arrows, columns, draw

I wish to create a table that looks something like this:

```
 A.       B.       C.
```

1. a -> b -> c

   d (diagonal up arrow going to b)
2. e -> f -> f

My apologies for the poor formatting but this is what I have in mind. I wish to have distinct columns (with headers) and have each set of rows numbered similar to above. How would this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way with package `listliketab` and standard packages:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{old-arrows}
\usepackage{listliketab}

\begin{document}

\storestyleof{enumerate}
\begin{listliketab}
\newcounter{tabenum}
\setcounter{tabenum}{0}
\newcommand{\tabitem}{\stepcounter{tabenum}\thetabenum. }
        \begin{tabular}{Lc@{} >{$}c<{$}@{}c@{} >{$}c<{$}@{}c}
             & A. & & B. & & C. \\
            \tabitem & a&\longrightarrow & b&\longrightarrow & c \\
             & d &\smash[t]{\rotatebox{45}{$\xrightarrow{\quad\enspace}$}} \\
            \tabitem & e&\longrightarrow & f &\longrightarrow& g
        \end{tabular}
\end{listliketab}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thank you! What if I were looking for $n$ columns, how would that change the script?

Comment: And sorry one more question, what if I also wanted a vertical arrow going in both directions from say $a$ to $d$?

Comment: With also the oblique arrow  from d to b?

Comment: Without the oblique is fine

Comment: I would stack  a smashed & rotated `\longleftrightarrow` under a, for instance. There would be another and simpler solution with `pstricks` (for all sorts of arrows)

Comment: Thank you, I am having some issue with consistent spacing as well using listliketab so I will look into pstricks.

Comment: Take a look more precisely at `pst-node`: the idea is to define the elements you want to link as pstricks nodes, and to linkthe node connections. This doesn't add any spacing in the resulting .pdf

Comment: Great, thank you!